# Objective-c Test if statusBarHidden

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to write tests to see if my statusBar is hidden. I was getting NO when I expected YES, so I put the test inside the code block and still receive NO

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;

    NSLog(@"CHECK");
    NSLog([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden ? @"Yes" : @"No");`
```

This returns

```
CHECK
NO
```

Does anyone know why this is the case? I would expect it to return YES

I'm new to iOS testing and just trying to figure it out

Comment: is the status bar hidden after you set it to YES ?

Answer (score 2):

This code does nothing:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES
```

If you want the status bar to hide, implement `prefersStatusBarHidden` in your view controller. That's what it's for.

Comment: Is there any way to test if the statusBar is Hidden?

Comment: You can _see_ whether it's hidden.